# Wrong Date Picker

Tags: java, android, youtube, datepicker

I have an application like this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czKLAx750N0

On real Phone run good, but on symulator with lower android version no. How solve this problem?

But in video have other datepicker than I. I need datepicker with calendar view. Now I have datepicker where I swipe days, months and years.

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
int rok,mes,den;
static final int DIALOG_ID=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
    rok = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mes =  cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    den = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    showDialogOnButtonClick();
}


public void showDialogOnButtonClick() {
    btn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    showDialog(DIALOG_ID);

                }
            }
    );
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if (id==DIALOG_ID)
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,dpickerListener, rok, mes, den);
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListener
        = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        rok=i;
        mes=i1 +1;
        den=i2;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, rok + "/" +mes + "/"+ den, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
}
```

I need the same datepicker which is in the video.

Comment: that style in lollipop and up only

Comment: and how made this style?

Comment: yes on my real phone with android 6.0 run good...

Comment: Fixed some typos and reworded a bit. Could you please add more details to the problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers

Try this library, I use it and it's really good.

Comment: thise pickers run on all version Android? or lollipoop and up too.

Comment: yup :) I've tested them on API 16.